# Track by $index with pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I use `$index` to retrieve item for editing, it works fine on first page, but on 2nd, 3rd and so on indexes start from zero again. 
This is my ngRepeat loop

```
<div class="row comment-table" ng-repeat="item in items ">
```

and this is at the bottom of my view where pagination is

```
<div>
    <ul ng-if="pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
        <li ng-class="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="setPage(1)">First</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
            <a ng-click="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="page in pager.pages" ng-class="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
            <a ng-click="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
        </li>               
        <li ng-class="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
            <a ng-click="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I think I should use `track` in my ng-repeat but there's no use if I track by `index`. I tried tracking by `item.id` but that doesn't seem to be the case either. I read about `filter:` but I didn't really get how to use it.  Do I add clas or function after it or use model name? Does anyone have some examples or have idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Basically you want to get the row index?

Comment: Check the answer below and see if this is what you require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to get the row index of the paginated table. If so you can use the below code:

```
$scope.rowIndex=(currentPage-1)*pageSize +$index+1;
```

where `currentPage` is the page you are on now, `pageSize` is the no. of items per page and `$index` is the index value of the row for that page.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I missed the beginning of calculation  that's why I couldn't get correct index. Thank you!